# An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, telerik, runtime-error

when i run the project and click the button i'm getting the bellow error but some times when refresh the page it's ok 
this error is:

Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadUtils.xdd533b8554f4809f.get_xc69acd7a502d05cf() +45
   Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadUtils.xdd533b8554f4809f..ctor(String rawHeaders, Encoding encoding) +1116
   Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadUtils.x36c7f9fd35fa4595.xd1f491285a514588(Int32 x10aaa7cdfa38f254, Int32 xca09b6c2b5b18485) +783
   Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadUtils.x36c7f9fd35fa4595.x54d4b26b2f8d3ec8(x5648daea895b1a09 x6a4d36d60e4f5261, RadUploadContext x014b4fadfce60f63) +884
   Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadHttpModule.xbae0920427925742(Object xe0292b9ed559da7d, EventArgs xfbf34718e704c6bc) +416
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +216
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +120
[the image shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiECx.png)

Comment: Unfortunately my crystal ball got smashed this morning and without it I haven't much chance to answer your question.  Maybe I could have a go without it, if you supplied a few clues?